# How to access express js server from inside local network using no-ip

Tags: node.js, express, networking, server, noip

I have problem ,when I am trying to connect to my express server using host that I have gotten from no-ip. I can't access it inside my router. I have tried my server machine and mobile which was connected to the same network but aslo I couldn't.
But when I tried to connect using mobile data I could access it. how can I solve this strange problem !?

Comment: its not strange, some routers simply dont/not configured to route back to itself over WAN (NAT Loopback), can you access your WAN ip and it forwards to the server?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone When I am trying to access my wan ip I can access router page which I can access from 192.168.1.1. Is it what you mean ?

Comment: no, go on google and enter *whats my ip*, copy paste it then put into your browser and append the express port, ie `http://123.123.123.123:8080`, if it fails to serve your app then your router may not support [nat loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning)

Comment: It doesn't , thanks